# left click logging off session- FC17

Tags: xorg, hardware-failure, touchpad, fedora-17

I am using FC-17 kernel 3.8.12-100 on an Asus k55vm laptop.

All of a sudden my left touchpad click is causing the session to log off without any notification. Initially I thought that it might be some hardware problem or something but it doesn't log off the terminal session (ctrl+alt+f2). Also it doesn't seem to be a problem of gnome shell because even at the time of login, the problem is there.

At that time my kernel version was 3.8.11-100. I thought that it must be a bug in the kernel and it so happened that kernel update was available. But even after updating I am not able to fix the problem.

The problem is only with left click and tapping the touchpad doesnt cause any problem.

This is not a fatal problem but an accidental click may lead to loss of data.

I had seen some issues with mouse click but none like this. It is just too strange. It seems to be some problem of X-server [my Xorg-server version is 1.12.4-2].

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem?

Is there any way of disabling the left click while retaining other functions of touchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been experiencing the same issue for a few days on my Acer S3 Ultrabook.  I even tried the other two kernels present in my grub boot menu. I am currently on 3.8.12 and the other two options were 3.8.11, 3.8.8. Neither worked, still had the issue.

Try pulling up a shell/terminal. I'm on gnome 3 so I hit alt+f2, typed in "gnome-shell" then sudo yum update. That did the trick! It'll happen one more time if you try using the mouse right after that update, but don't freak out. I loggged in again and the mouse worked for me.

If you don't want a full update, then try running the update for the syntapics touchpad itself.

yum install xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.6.3-4.fc17.x86_64

I hope googlers find this solution quickly as I did not.

http://ums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=291206

Comment: i ran an update when i detected the problem and my kernel was updated too.. but the problem didnt get solved.. i shall try reinstalling touchpad driver

Comment: i think it was the problem of an incompatible synaptics driver.. the new driver works fine.. thanks